# Curl not saving the file with original name

Tags: windows, curl, cmd

I am downloading a file using CURL. The file URL is dynamic. Since I wanted to save the file with the same name, I am using curl -O to download to a folder

The file gets downloaded but the file is saved with the extension
i.e., "csv"

I am trying to download a CSV file.

I see this in the header

`HTTP/1.1 200 OK
X-Powered-By: Servlet/3.0
Last-Modified: Wed, 23 May 2012 07:23:15 GMT
Cache-Control: public, proxy-revalidate, s-maxage=3
Content-Type: text/csv;charset=UTF-16LE
Content-Disposition: attachment; filename*=utf-8''all_open.csv
Content-Language: en-US
Transfer-Encoding: chunked
Date: Mon, 10 Mar 2014 13:10:41 GMT`

Unfortunately, the downaloded file has the name `csv` and not `all_open.csv`

Any idea what I might be doing wrong?

The curl command I use is

`C:/curl-7.35.0/bin/curl -D - -k -b 'C:/workdir/cookies/auth_cookie.txt' -H 'Content-Type: application/csv' -H 'Accept: text/csv' -O -J -X GET 'https://server/_9jHFQDtoEeGi16hvdCIrXQ?_mediaType=text/csv'`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Whatever the cause of your problem with `curl` you can extract the file name from the headers separately. To do so put something like this in a batch file (e.g., `download.cmd`):

```
set CURL=C:\curl-7.35.0\bin\curl
set URL=https://server/_9jHFQDtoEeGi16hvdCIrXQ?_mediaType=text/csv
set OPTIONS=-k -b "C:\workdir\cookies\auth_cookie.txt" -H "Content-Type: application/csv" -H "Accept: text/csv"
%CURL% %OPTIONS% -X GET "%URL%" --head | findstr filename > filename.tmp
for /f "delims==, tokens=2" %%i in (filename.tmp) do %CURL% %OPTIONS% -X GET "%URL%" -o %%i
del /q filename.tmp
```